# Problems with executing a method with asynctask from the main activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-actionbar

So, I have an app which uses the Viewpager and swiping. I got 3 fragments which contains a listview, and a custom adapter to set the rows.

In each fragment, I have a method to call the asynctask and fetch the JSON. I run this method in the onActivityCreated.

When I start the app, everything is working fine, the progressdialog shows, and all the list's are being set with the correct data.

The problem is that i want to be able to refresh all the lists when click the refresh-button in the actionbar (to check for new tweets).

The only way I've been able to use the refreshbutton is when I use the onOptionsItemSelected() in the MainActivity.

So I'm thinking, I can just call the methods who then again calls the asynctask.

```
case R.id.menu_refresh:
MSFTHost host = new MSFTHost();
host.getTweets();
    ...
```

But when I click the button, the whole thing force closes:

```
02-05 21:46:57.959: W/dalvikvm(15292): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught    exception (group=0x40d5a930)02-05 21:46:58.045:
E/AndroidRuntime(15292): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292):    at com.sandan.HostingNorge.MSFTHost$DownloadWebPageTask.onPostExecute(MSFTHost.java:95)
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292):    at com.sandan.HostingNorge.MSFTHost$DownloadWebPageTask.onPostExecute(MSFTHost.java:1)
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5202)
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
02-05 21:46:58.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15292):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the line 95 contains this:

```
listItems.add(new  GetListItems(oneObject.getString("text"),oneObject.getString("created_at"),obj
                                .getString("profile_image_url"), obj
                                .getString("screen_name")));
```

I tried clearing listItems, but it didn't have any effect.

Any help please?

Edit:
If I was unclear, I want to get the JSON again and show in the list, just like on the first run.

Comment: check what object is null oneObject or object !? and you can paste more source code.

Comment: @bongo What code do you want me to show? I tried debugging, and nothing is null (from what I saw, not so good with the debugger...), It's exactly the same data from the first run